# Clear views cache after node inserted in Drupal 7

Tags: views, caching

I've views which list the list of node details. I've set views cache for 30 mins.
I want to clear particular views cache when insert a node.
I've tried below code to clear cache but there is no difference in my page.

```
function phponwebsites_node_insert($node) {
 if ($node->type == 'tasks') {
   views_invalidate_cache();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next snippet should work for you

```
cache_clear_all('MY_VIEW_NAME:', 'cache_views_data', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to clear your view display cache.

```
$view = views_get_view('VIEW-NAME');
$view->set_display('VIEW-DISPLAY');
$cache = $view->display_handler->get_plugin('cache');
$cache->cache_flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

See [cache_clear_all](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/7) function. Try this if you need to clear only views cache :

```
cache_clear_all('*', 'cache_views', TRUE);
```

**Edit :** 
Try [Cache Action](https://www.drupal.org/project/cache_actions) module. It depends on [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

> Cache actions provides rules actions for clearing drupal caches.
>
> It currently provides actions for:
>
> Clearing Drupal cache bins Clearing CSS/JS cache Clearing The cache of
>   specific views Clearing The cache of specific panel pages Clearing The
>   cache of specific mini panels

Comment: I've tried your code in my hook_node_insert() but it didn't clear cache for views

Comment: Just try `cache_clear_all()`.

Comment: If i used cache_clear_all(), then all caches are deleted. Thats why i need to delete only views cache

Comment: Ok then try to change it to `cache_clear_all(NULL, 'cache_views', TRUE);`.

Comment: Sorry. i've used this also. but views cache is not cleared

Comment: Well, it have no issue. I tried this code and check the `cache_views` table. For me it working fine. But yeah I have edit my answer. See if solution works for you.

Comment: Thats also fine. But i don't like to use extra module. I'll hope, it can be done without any module and rules