# Executing view twice with different filters returns same results

Tags: 7, views

Here's my simple scenario :

- Execute view with exposed filter (min & max dates)
- If there are no results, execute again with min date = 0 to get all results

Unfortunately, the query static cache will execute the same query twice.

```
$view           = views_get_view('my_view');
$view->set_display('default');

$date       = $view->get_item('default', 'filter', 'created');
$date['value']['min']   = date('Y-m-d', $date_from);
$date['value']['max']   = date('Y-m-d', $date_to);
$view->set_item('default', 'filter', 'created', $date);

$view->pre_execute();
$view->execute();
$results = $view->result;

$view->destroy();

// do logic here to determine if view needs to be queried a second time

$view           = views_get_view('my_view');
$view->set_display('default');

$date       = $view->get_item('default', 'filter', 'created');
$date['value']['min']   = date('Y-m-d', 0);
$date['value']['max']   = date('Y-m-d', $date_to);
$view->set_item('default', 'filter', 'created', $date);

$view->pre_execute();
$view->execute();
$results2 = $view->result;

$view->destroy();

// $results and $results2 are identical
```

If I comment the first part of the code, the second query will work correctly and $results2 contains a lot more results.

I've tried answers from this question [1], but no luck.

The only solution I found is to clear the entire static cache with `drupal_static_reset();`

How to elegantly solve this problem? I believe clearing only the static cache for the queries will solve this, but I fail to find the good $name argument.

[1] [Clear views cache after node inserted in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163588)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct static cache to clear in order to solve the issue :

```
drupal_static_reset('views_exposed_form_cache');
```

I guess since the exposed filters are not supposed to change during a request, the developpers did not anticipate this.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to [`views_get_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view/7.x-3.x) is `$reset`:

> If TRUE, reset this entry in the load cache.

So second time around you just need to pass that:

```
$view = views_get_view('my_view');
$view->set_display('default');

...

$view = views_get_view('my_view', TRUE);
```

That will reset the static cache and the data will be fresh.

Comment: It looked promising, but unfortunately it has no effect in my case